# How we are assigning values to GLFloat to draw a line in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, line, draw

Finally Mr.Chris helped me to draw a line using GLKview and drawInRect: method. It is working fine. But, i need some clarifications,

1. How we are assigning values to GLFloat?

   ```
   const GLfloat line[] = 
   {
       -1.0f, -1.5f, //point A : What is -1.0f and -1.5f ? These are x and y or something.
       1.5f, -1.0f, //point B : What is 1.5f and -1.0f ? These are x and y or something. 
   };
   ```

Because, i am confusing to set a values here. How it is taking x,y or length? If it is silly question please accept my apologies. Please clarify my doubts on this.

1. How to set background image for GLKViewController? I have an image to set background but, i don't know where i need to set that?

Sample viewDidLoad code

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
        {
            [super viewDidLoad];
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"GameDesign03.png"]];

            self.context = [[[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2] autorelease];

            if (!self.context) {
                NSLog(@"Failed to create ES context");
            }

            GLKView *view = (GLKView *)self.view;
            view.context = self.context;
            view.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24;

        [self setupGL]; 
    }

- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    glClearColor(0.65f, 0.65f, 0.65f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    [self.effect prepareToDraw];  // Prepare the effect for rendering

    const GLfloat line[]=
    {
        -1.0f, -1.5f, 
         1.5f, -1.0f
    };


    GLuint bufferObjectNameArray; //Create an handle for a buffer object array

    glGenBuffers(1, &bufferObjectNameArray); //Have OpenGL generate a buffer name and store it in the buffer object array

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferObjectNameArray); //Bind the buffer object array to the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER target buffer

    //Send the line data over to the target buffer in GPU RAM
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(line), line, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition); //Enable vertex data to be fed down the graphics pipeline to be drawn

    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2, NULL); //Specify how the GPU looks up the data 

    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2); // render 

 }
```

Please help on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to post the code where you actually draw the lines. Usually, you send OpenGL a list of vertices. You tell it whether the coordinates are 2D or 3D, and that determines whether they are (x,y) pairs or (x,y,z) triples. As for the background image - controllers don't draw anything. You would need to draw it to your GLKView before doing your other drawing. You could, for example, draw a textured quad covering the whole area, then draw your lines.

Comment: I have added the code where am draw the line. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to answer your first question, on this line:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2, NULL); //Specify how the GPU looks up the data
```

you're setting the `size` argument to 2, which tells OpenGL that there are 2 components per vertex attribute. They are the endpoints of the lines.

And to answer your second question, you need to draw the background image before drawing the lines, as mentioned in my comment above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your spot response. Please clarify this doubt, Where we are giving the starting point,ending point and length of the line. What this code is doing? 
const GLfloat line[] = 
{
    -1.0f, -1.5f, //point A 
    1.5f, -1.0f, //point B 
}; Please clarify this one. Thanks in advance. Waiting for your reply and also am searching for guidelines. Thanks.

Comment: That line of code is simply creating an array containing the vertices. It doesn't tell OpenGL anything by itself. The call to `glBufferData()` sends the array up to the video card. The meaning of the values -`1.0f`, `-1.5f` and `1.5f`, `-1.0f` will depend on how you've set up your world. The call to `glViewport()` and one of `glOrtho()`, `glFrustum()`, or `gluPerspective()` will determine what those values represent. If you haven't set the transformation matrixes, then your world probably stretches from -1.0 to 1.0 in both x and y.